# Select (highlight) children in a treepanel with mouse

Tags: extjs, tree

I want to highlight some nodes in my treepanel with my mouse like if it was a textarea. 
See the image below to understand what I mean with "highlight with my mouse". Is there a property which permits me doing that?
[image]

Comment: Do you want to make them selectable and copyable ? Is it that what you mean ?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Yes that's it !

Comment: Could you add the solution as answer ? (to keep SO clean) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution has been found:

**IMPORTANT** I found how to do, just add `viewConfig: {enableTextSelection : true}` in your tree.panel